# Does Action and Reaction arise simultaneously or one follows the other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, causality

When we do an action there is a reaction, but the question is does the action precede the reaction or do the action and reaction arise simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

The “action” and “reaction” are just labels. They happen at the same time. In fact, because they happen at the same time many physicists feel that the “action and reaction” terminology is misleading. It is preferable to call them “third law pairs” instead.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question; it is a very typcial confusion.

If you're talking about forces, then yes, they are absolutely simultaneous. That's why I find "action and reaction" a really bad name ellection. "Reaction" suggests that there is some kind of lag, some kind of "revenge", which takes some time. No, action and reaction forces appear at the same time. Consequently, we should not talk about forces, but "force pairs". One cannot exists without another. As soon as there is a force, there is another one, same modulus but opposite direction.

On the other hand, if we're not talking about forces, it depends. For example, if you push a spring, the spring reacts re-expanding itself. But that's not a force, it is a process. Each force involved in the process satisfies Newton's third law with the former simultaneity.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to distinguish between statics and dynamics.

First statics:
if you compress a spring (or any elastic material) then that elicits an opposing force from the spring. That is a context where there is clearly an initiator and something that happens in response to that.

In the case of *dynamics* the setup is inherently *symmetrical*.

Take the example of [bolas flying through the air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RON9rWcALWc) (demonstration video on youtube)

Let me symplify that to two balls, and for now let me only consider the forces on the two balls.

Because of the way they are thrown the two balls are circling around their common center of mass; the tension of the connecting rope provides the required centripetal force.

Both balls are in circular motion, both balls are being accelerated. For both the balls we have that the force necessary for that acceleration is provided by the inertia of the other ball.

If we label them 'ball A' and 'ball B':
Why is ball A capable of exerting that force upon ball B? That arises from the inertia of ball A, and the amount of force exerted is described by the expression $F=ma$.

In perfect symmetry:
Why is ball B capable of exerting that force upon ball A? That arises from the inertia of ball B and the amount of force exerted is described by the expression $F=ma$.

The way that the motion proceeds is such that there is no such thing as an 'initiator' and a 'responder'.

Let me emphasize the importance of $F=ma$ in this context.

When you are hammering in a nail you are using the inertial mass of the hammerhead to exert a force. You swing the hammer and when the hammer hits the nail you get a deceleration spike of the hammerhead. That deceleration spike gives a force spike. That very short burst of an extremely high force pushes the nail deeper into the wood.

For the flying bolas there is no such thing as a distinction between one ball being the 'forcer' and the other ball being the 'forced'.

The amount of force that each ball can exert on the other ball (via the rope) is given by the expression $F=ma$, and the amount of force that is required for the circular motion is also given by $F=ma$.